# Prove that $C^n(\mathbb{R})$ is a subspace using induction.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, induction

Let $V$ be the set of all functions $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$.

Prove by induction that $C^n(\mathbb{R})$ is a subspace of $V$.

I feel that this could be shown directly without much issue using the linearity of differentiation and some results such as 'the sum of two continuous functions is continuous' etc.

I may be misunderstanding the question, though.

I am unsure how induction comes into the picture, I can show that $C^0(\mathbb{R})$ is a subspace, how would I proceed from there? I feel as if this will draw on the principle of strong induction.

Comment: By plain ordinary induction, you prove "if $f$ and $g$ are $n$ times continuously differentiable, then so is $f+g$" for all $n$. (And for scalar multiples of course too.)

Answer (score 1):

You only have to show, that assuming $C^n(\mathbb{R})\subseteq V$ for some fixed natural $n$, it follows that also $C^{n+1}(\mathbb{R})\subseteq V$. Hint: What information do you have or can you proof about both, the sets $C^n(\mathbb{R})$ and $C^{n+1}(\mathbb{R})$? Finally apply the transivity of the "$\subseteq$"-relation.